# Injective morphism between smooth projectives varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth projectives varieties and $f:X \to Y$ be an injective morphism. Is it true that the induced morphism $f^* : k(Y) \to k(X)$ is surjective (we can assume $k$ algebraically closed)?

Even in the particular case when $X$ is a subvariety of $Y$, I wasn't able to show that any $g \in k(X)$ can be extended to some $f \in k(Y)$.
(My goal is to show that the dimension of a subvariety $X$ is smaller that the dimension of $Y$, which I think is true).

Thank you!

Comment: If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is not dominant, there is no pullback map of rational functions.

Comment: @Nefertiti: can't we just define in general $f^*(g) = g \circ f$ for any $g \in k(Y)$ ? Thank you!

Comment: Dear Alphonse: no, because if $f$ is not dominant, the image of $f$ could be contained in the indeterminacy locus of $g$.

Comment: See I.4.4 in Hartshorne. Moreover, exercise II.2.18 in Hartshorne tells that $f : A \to B$ is a surjective morphism of rings iff $f' : Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ is a closed immersion of schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in various comments, the formation of function fields is not functorial for all morphisms, but only for dominant ones.

This is related to the fact that a morphism of fields is necessarily injective.  If it is furthermore surjective (as is proposed in the OP) then 
it is an isomorphism.  In the context of maps $K(Y) \to K(X)$ induced by morphism $X \to Y,$ this is equivalent to $X \to Y$ being birational.

Finally, just to connect to the hypotheses of the OP, one could note that a dominant morphism of projective varieties that is also an embedding (and hence a closed immersion) is necessarily an isomorphism.

Comment: For me, we could just define $f^*(g) = g \circ f$ for any $g \in k(Y)$. Is this a wrong definition (this doesn't require $f$ to be dominant – I wasn't aware of this notion, however)?

Comment: @Alphonse: If $f$ is not dominant, then the image of $f$ might lie entirely in the locus where $g$ is undefined, so your "definition" is not well-defined.

Comment: @tracing: hey, that's what i said! :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it seemed to need repeating :)  (I was one of the people who up voted your comment!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but the answer to your goal can be found in the first section of Hartshorne. Dimension is defined in terms of longest chain of irreducible closed subsets, so it's just purely a topological idea. With this definition, it is pretty quick to get what you want. Using the Nullstellensatz, we can understand dimension in terms of height of primes and connect our definitions of dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. I have another definition of dimension of $X$, which is the transcendance degree of $k(X)$ over $k$.

Comment: See Hartshorne Thm 1.8A to connect your definition to other definitions.

Comment: @Alphonse Thinking more about your original question, the answer is going to be no. Take the subvariety $\{x = 0 \}$ in $\mathbb A^2$. If the map on function fields were to be surjective, then its bijective (nonzero maps out of fields are injective). But the function fields are $k(t)$ and $k(x, y)$, respectively, which cannot be isomorphic (as $k$-algebras, since they have different transcendence degree).

Comment: @hwong557 This is not the issue. Obviously we have a surjective map since image of the constant maps $k \hookrightarrow K(\mathbb{A}^2)$ will cover $A(Y = \{ (0,0) \})$. The problem is that it's not actually defined on all of $K(\mathbb{A}^2)$ since the morphism $Y \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ is not dominant. For example, in the case of $y/x$ there is no way to inlcude the origin in the domain. The OP's question is true in the case of dominant morphisms and true in the general case, with some domain considerations

Comment: @basket I see now. Great example thanks.

Comment: @basket: Sorry, I don't understand the example. What is $A(Y)$, if $Y=\{(0,0)\}$ ? So you don't consider $X=\{(0,y) : y \in k\}$ as in hwong557's example? I'm a bit confused… Are you saying that the inclusion $X \to \Bbb A^2$ induces a surjective map $k(\Bbb A^2) \to k(X)$? Thank you!

Comment: @basket: As for my 1st question, is $A(Y)$ the same as $V(Y) =$ set of polynomials that vanish on $Y$ (we can see a polynomial as the associated polynomial function $Y_0 := \Bbb A^2 \to \Bbb A^1$) ?